# Best place to load data when navigating XamarinForms Prism 6?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism-6

One of the cool features in Prism 6 is the deep linking and passing parameters. In a lot of cases, you'd want to use this parameter to look up data from a web service. Ideally this would be using async/await to get the data. Where is the best place to do this? The OnNavigatedTo method for example is a void.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't have a case for Deep Linking yet, I am doing many loads on many pages inside OnNavigatedTo and it is working great!

Here is a sample:

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    if (parameters != null &&
        parameters.ContainsKey("MyKey"))
    {
        SomePrivateFieldInViewModel = (YourVariable)parameters["MyKey"];
        //SomeWork
    }

    GetItems();
}

private async void GetItems()
{
    try
    {
        SomeListInViewModel = await WebServices.GetEntity(SomePrivateFieldInViewModel);
        //SomeWork
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //SomeWork
    }
}
```

Comment: But you don't await your call to GetItems so its not really doing async code. Don't you get a warning from the compiler on that line?

Comment: No warming at all. During runtime the OnNavigatedTo() will fire GetItems() and finish.

Comment: (Pressed ENTER too early) No warming at all. During runtime the OnNavigatedTo() will fire GetItems() and finish. At this point, GetItems() is already running and will keep doing its things until its finish. Since user is already in the screen/page the GetItems() also set a isLoading to true in the very beginning (did not put that in my answer). This isLoading is a bool with NotifyPropertyChange so my View will show a loading control.

Comment: I don't doubt it will work but I would expect the code to be run in sync mode not async mode. I wonder if it's because you have async void instead of async Task. However, if you google 'c# async void' there seem to be a lot of posts saying that's not a good thing.